# common ways to pass state from cmdlet to cmdlet

Tags: powershell

I am creating my own set of cmdlets. They all need the same state data (like location of DB and credentials for connecting to DB). I assume this must be a common need and wonder what the common idiom for doing this is.

the obvious one is something like

```
$db = my-make-dbcreds db=xxx creds=yyyy ...
my-verb1 $db | my-verb2 $db -foo 42...
my-verb8 $db bar wiz
.....
```

but i was wondering about other ways. Can I silently pipe the state from one to another. I know I can do this if state is the only thing I pipe but these cmdlets return data

Can I set up global variables that I use if the user doesnt specify state in the command

Comment: You can absolutely use global variables. Just declare them in global scope and name and use them like `$global:foo`. If you have the NetworkSwitch module on your system, you can check its source code out - there are global variables used by that script module. Note: you should really check your globals when using them to make sure they contain what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Passing the information state through the pipe is a little lost on me. You could update your cmdlets to return objects that the next cmdlet will accept via [ValueFromPipeline](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847743.aspx). When you mentioned

> like location of DB and credentials for connecting to DB

the best this I could think that you want is....

**SPLATTING!**

> [Splatting](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj672955.aspx) is a method of passing a collection of parameter
>       values to a command as unit. Windows PowerShell associates 
>       each value in the collection with a command parameter.

In its simplest form

```
$params = @{
    Filter = "*.txt"
    Path = "C:\temp"
}

Get-ChildItem @params
```

Create a hashtable of parameters and values and splat them to the command. The you can edit the table as the unique call to the cmdlet would allow.

```
$params.Path = "C:\eventemperor"
Get-ChildItem @params
```

I changed the `path` but left the `filter` the same. You also dont have to have everything in `$params` you splat and use other parameters in the same call.

It is just a matter of populating the variables as you see fit and changing them as the case requires.

**Spewing on the pipeline**

Pretty that is what it is actually called. If you use advanced function parameters you can chain properties from one cmdlet to the next if you really wanted to. FWIW I think splatting is better in your case but have a look at the following.

```
function One{
    param(
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true,
                ValueFromPipeline=$True,
                ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
                [String[]]
                $Pastry
    )

    write-host "You Must Like $Pastry"
    Write-Output (New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject -Property @{Pastry= $pastry})
    # If you have at least PowerShell 3.0
    # [pscustomobject]@{Pastry= $pastry}
}
```

Simple function that writes the variable `$pastry` to the console but also outputs an object for the next pipe. So running the command

```
"Eclairs" | One | One | Out-Null
```

We get the following output

```
You Must Like Eclairs
You Must Like Eclairs
```

We need to pipe to Out-Null at the end else you would get this.

```
Pastry                                                                                                                                                                                                               
------                                                                                                                                                                                                               
{Eclairs}
```

Perhaps not the best example but you should get the idea. If you wanted to extract information between the pipe calls you could use [`Tee-Object`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849937.aspx).

```
"Eclair" | One | Tee-Object -Variable oneresults | One | Out-Null
$oneresults
```

### Consider Parameter Default Values

Revisiting this concept after trying to find a better way to pass SQL connection information between many function working against the same database. I am not sure if this is the best thing to do but it certainly simplifies thing for me.

The basic idea is to add a rule for your cmdlet or wildcard rule if your cmdlets share a naming convention. For instance I have a series of functions that interact with our ticketing system. They all start with `Get-Task....` and all configured with SQL connection information.

```
$invokeSQLParameters = @{
    ServerInstance = "serverName"
    Username = $Credentials.UserName
    Password = $Credentials.GetNetworkCredential().Password
}
$PSDefaultParameterValues.Add("New-Task*:Connection",$invokeSQLParameters)
$PSDefaultParameterValues.Add("Get-Task*:Connection",$invokeSQLParameters)
```

So now in my functions I have a parameter called `Connection` that will always be populated with `$invokeSQLParameters` as long as the above is done before the call. I still use splatting as well

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $getCommentsQuery @Connection
```

You can read up more about this at [about_parameters_default_values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parameters_default_values?view=powershell-5.1)

Comment: the last one is what I meant by sending things through the pipe. But the problem is that my cmdlets need to put useful things on the pipe - ie get-data returns data from the database

Comment: @pm100 Most people would use splatting for sharing connection information between calls/cmdlets. In the case of my pipe suggestion I can make an edit if you would like. Tee-Object would help break out information if you need to save it.

Comment: @pm100 I was just asking myself the same question recently and was disappointed to find my own answer to this lacking. See I know more now than I did I add a section at the bottom of my answer that is basically what I do now.